# nginx location not opening static site

Tags: nginx, web-server, nginx-unit

My nginx configuration is not working as expected. This is my location config in nginx.conf:

```
 location / {
            proxy_pass "https://localhost:9002";

        }

        location /app  { 

            root /usr/local/var/www;
            index index.html;
            # autoindex off;
            try_files $uri /index.html;

         }
```

- When I am doing /app/some-url its opening http://localhost:9002. I expect it should load my static site
- When I comment location / block then it works fine and opens static site.

Comment: In which directory is `index.html`?

Comment: @RichardSmith in /usr/local/var/www

Answer (score 2):

with the `root` directive, the pathname of a static resource is calculated by concatenating the `root` value with the URI. In your case, the URI `/app/foo.css` is expected to be located at `/usr/local/var/www/app/foo.css`. Notice that `app` is a subdirectory within the `www` directory. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

The last term of a `try_files` directive is a URI, error code or named location. The URIs of your static application begin with `/app`, so the default URI should probably be `/app/index.html` to locate the correct file. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For reasons of simplicity and efficiency, the best solution is to move all of your files into a directory with the same name as the URI prefix (e.g. `app`).

For example:

```
/usr/local/var/www/app/index.html
/usr/local/var/www/app/foo.js
/usr/local/var/www/app/foo.css
```

The Nginx configuration would look like:

```
location /app {
    root /usr/local/var/www;
    index index.html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html;
}
```

---

If the directory containing the static application, is not the same as the URI prefix used to access it, you will need to use an `alias` directive or other tricks to rewrite the URIs so that `root` will work. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
/usr/local/var/www/index.html
/usr/local/var/www/foo.js
/usr/local/var/www/foo.css
```

The Nginx configuration would look like:

```
location /app {
    alias /usr/local/var/www;
    index index.html;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /app/index.html last; }
}
```

The `location` and `alias` values should both end with a `/` or neither end with a `/`. Avoid using `alias` and `try_files` together, due to this [long term issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Thanks, @richard for an answer, I am getting 403 now while loading `/app`

Comment: Is there an entry in the error log?

Comment: directory index of "/usr/local/var/www" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Comment: It's looking for a file at `/usr/local/var/www/index.html` but cannot find it.

Answer (score -1):

Move the `location /app` above `location /` otherwise / takes precedence and `location /app` is ignored.

Comment: The order of location block does not affect the execution order.

Comment: That is true only for regexp locations. Not in this case